# Qweb - Error - Company Logo not found while printing

Tags: report, odoo

In Settings-> Companies -> Added an image [Logo]. In two of the reports, this logo is printed. But when printing sale order I get this error

[Error while printing the sale order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHrWX.png) 
The code of the reports in which the logo appears is same as sale order report. In those two reports, it takes the company logo & prints it. No error. But I get this error only in sale order report. Can anyone please help me fix this error?

Code for your reference :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <img t-if="company.logo" t-att-src="'data:image/png;base64,%s' % company.logo" style="max-height: 45px;"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-9 text-right" style="margin-top:20px;" t-field="company.rml_header1"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<template id="report_saleorder">
    <t t-call="report.html_container">
        <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="doc">
            <t t-call="module.report_saleorder_document" t-lang="doc.partner_id.lang"/>
            <br/><br/><br/>
```

should be given before t t-call="module.report_saleorder_document" t-lang="doc.partner_id.lang" and now it works buddy!

Answer (score 0):

`company` is not global variable and it will work with every image that you have on your object. If you were to add image for your object then your object variable reference and  field name that hold image should be right expression here.

And If you trying to add the company logo on your report then you need to user company_id field on your object to reach to image of company.

Bests

Comment: I tried with company_id. Still it does not work. company_id.logo

Comment: I tried with company_id. Still it does not work. These ways don't work. Got an error. 'QWebException: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_fields''         1. company_id.logo 2. res_company.logo 3. partner_id.company_id.logo 4. partner_id.company.logo 5. doc.partner_id.company_id.                                                                                 Please tell me in detail what must be done to print the logo in sale order report

Comment: Code line reference: ' <template id="report_saleorder">
    <t t-call="report.html_container">
        <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="doc">
            <t t-call="ajax_accounts.report_saleorder_document" t-lang="doc.partner_id.lang"/>
         <div class="header">
           <div class="row">
       <div class="row mt0 mb0">
        <div class="col-xs-7">
             <img t-if="res_company.logo" t-att-src="'data:image/png;base64,%s' % res_company.logo" style="max-height: 50 px;align:left;"/>
     <div class="col-xs-9 text-right" style="margin-top:20px;" t-field="company.rml_header1"/>'

Comment: Can you get full report xml and I can tell you but with standard sale report you need say o.company_id.logo

Answer (score 0):

```
@shodowsjedi
Below is the xml code for your reference

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
<data>
<template id="report_saleorder_document">
   <t t-set="doc" t-value="doc.with_context({'lang':doc.partner_id.lang})" />
        <div class="page">
            <br/><br/><br/><br/>
            <h2>
                <span t-if="doc.state not in ['draft','sent']">Order # </span>
                <span t-if="doc.state in ['draft','sent']">Quotation # </span>
                <span t-field="doc.name"/>
            </h2>

            <div class="row mt32 mb32" id="informations">
                <div t-if="doc.client_order_ref" class="col-xs-3">
                    <strong>Your Reference:</strong>
                    <p t-field="doc.client_order_ref"/>
                </div>
                <div t-if="doc.user_id.name" class="col-xs-3">
                    <strong>Salesperson:</strong>
                    <p t-field="doc.user_id"/>
                </div>
                <div name="payment_term" t-if="doc.payment_term_id" class="col-xs-3">
                    <strong>Payment Term:</strong>
                    <p t-field="doc.payment_term_id"/>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Is there a discount on at least one line? -->
            <t t-set="display_discount" t-value="any([l.discount for l in doc.order_line])"/>

            <table class="table table-condensed">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Description</th>
                        <th class="text-right">Quantity</th>
                        <th class="text-right">Unit Price</th>
                        <th t-if="display_discount" class="text-right"><span groups="sale.group_discount_per_so_line">Disc.(%)</span></th>
                        <th class="text-right">Taxes</th>
                        <th class="text-right">Price</th>
                    </tr>
               </thead>
               <tbody class="sale_tbody">
                    <t t-foreach="doc.order_line" t-as="l">
                        <tr t-if="l.product_uom_qty">
                            <td>
                               <span t-field="l.name"/>
                            </td>
                            <td class="text-right">
                                <span t-field="l.product_uom_qty"/>
                                <span groups="product.group_uom" t-field="l.product_uom"/>
                            </td>
                            <td class="text-right">
                                <span t-field="l.price_unit"/>
                            </td>
                            <td t-if="display_discount" class="text-right" groups="sale.group_discount_per_so_line">
                                <span t-field="l.discount"/>
                            </td>
                            <td class="text-right">
                                <span t-esc="', '.join(map(lambda x: (x.description or x.name), l.tax_id))"/>
                            </td>
                            <td class="text-right">
                                <span t-field="l.price_subtotal"
                                    t-field-options='{"widget": "monetary", "display_currency": "doc.pricelist_id.currency_id"}'/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </t>
                </tbody>
            </table>

            <div class="row" name="total">
                <div class="col-xs-4 pull-right">
                    <table class="table table-condensed">
                        <tr class="border-black">
                            <td><strong>Total Without Taxes</strong></td>
                            <td class="text-right">
                                <span t-field="doc.amount_untaxed"
                                    t-field-options='{"widget": "monetary", "display_currency": "doc.pricelist_id.currency_id"}'/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Taxes</td>
                            <td class="text-right">
                                <span t-field="doc.amount_tax"
                                    t-field-options='{"widget": "monetary", "display_currency": "doc.pricelist_id.currency_id"}'/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="border-black">
                            <td><strong>Total</strong></td>
                            <td class="text-right">
                                <span t-field="doc.amount_total"
                                    t-field-options='{"widget": "monetary", "display_currency": "doc.pricelist_id.currency_id"}'/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>

            <p t-field="doc.note" />
            <p t-if="doc.payment_term_id.note">
                <span t-field="doc.payment_term_id.note"/>
            </p>
            <p t-if="not doc.payment_term_id and doc.partner_id.property_payment_term_id">
                <span t-field="doc.partner_id.property_payment_term_id.note"/>
            </p>
            <p id="fiscal_position_remark" t-if="doc.fiscal_position_id and doc.fiscal_position_id.note">
                <strong>Fiscal Position Remark:</strong>
                <span t-field="doc.fiscal_position_id.note"/>
            </p>
            <div class="oe_structure"/>
            <br/><br/><br/><br/>
            <div class="text-center">
                <p class="list-inline">
                    ***************************
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
</template>



<template id="report_saleorder">
    <t t-call="report.html_container">
        <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="doc">
            <t t-call="module.report_saleorder_document" t-lang="doc.partner_id.lang"/>
            <br/><br/><br/>

            <div class="header">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="row mt0 mb0">
                    <div class="col-xs-7">
                         <img t-if="doc.company_id.logo" t-att-src="'data:image/png;base64,%s' % doc.company_id.logo" style="max-height: 50 px;align:left;"/>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-9 text-right" style="margin-top:20px;" t-field="company.rml_header1"/>

                    <div class="row zero_min_height">
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <div style="border-bottom: 1px solid black;"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                    <div><span><strong>Customer Address:</strong></span></div>
                    <div><span t-field="doc.partner_id.name"/></div>
                    <div><span t-field="doc.partner_id.street"/><br/><span t-field="doc.partner_id.street2"/></div>
                    <div><span t-field="doc.partner_id.city"/><span> - </span><span t-field="doc.partner_id.zip"/></div>
                    <div><span t-field="doc.partner_id.state_id.name"/><span>,</span><span t-field="doc.partner_id.country_id.name"/></div>
                    <div><span t-if="doc.partner_id.pan_number">PAN:<span t-field="doc.partner_id.pan_number"/></span></div>

                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 col-xs-offset-9">
                    <strong t-if="doc.state not in ['draft','sent']">Date Ordered:</strong>
                    <strong t-if="doc.state in ['draft','sent']">Quotation Date:</strong>
                    <p t-field="doc.date_order"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="footer">

           <div class="text-center" style="border-top: 1px solid black;">
                <p class="list-inline">
                    ***************************************
                </p>
                <ul class="list-inline">
                <li>Page:</li>
                <li><span class="page"/></li>
                <li>/</li>
                <li><span class="topage"/></li>
            </ul>
           </div>

           </div>
        </t>
    </t>
</template>
</data>
</openerp>

**Error when running the above code
QWebException: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_fields'**
```

Comment: <template id="report_saleorder">
    <t t-call="report.html_container">
        <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="doc">
            <t t-call="module.report_saleorder_document" t-lang="doc.partner_id.lang"/>
            <br/><br/><br/>                                                                                       <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="doc"> should be given before <t t-call="module.report_saleorder_document" t-lang="doc.partner_id.lang"/> and now it works buddy!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your company value is not getting populated, so its not finding the logo.
If its a single company, try this instead,

```
<img t-if="res_company.logo" t-att-src="image_data_uri(res_company.logo)" style="max-height: 100px;"/>
```